# Unity Update (5.3.1) causing component errors

Tags: text, unity-game-engine, updates, nullreferenceexception, unityscript

I have recently updated my Unity Editor from 5.2.2 (I think) to 5.3.1 and a bunch of script errors occurred as a result. NB: scripts are in uJS.

A reoccurring issue seems to be related to the UI Text component. Previous references such as `var buttonText = instButton.GetComponentInChildren(Text);`now produce the error `BCE0019: 'text' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Component'.`

Have tried to resolve this through casting the reference as `var buttonText : Text = instButton.GetComponentInChildren(Text);`. However this only changes the error message to:

```
 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
     UnityEngine.UI.Graphic.OnRebuildRequested () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Graphic.cs:466)
     UnityEngine.UI.GraphicRebuildTracker.OnRebuildRequested () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/GraphicRebuildTracker.cs:33)
     UnityEngine.CanvasRenderer.RequestRefresh ()
```

The cause of which I am not entirely sure, however have read that this may be related to missing scripts in the package (not sure how this could be related to this issue).

If anyone can enlighten me as to why this may be occurring I would be incredibly grateful. Many thanks in advance, Ryan

Comment: `Text` does not appear to be a component type (I can't find it in the reference pages), maybe you mean `MeshText`?  I cannot tell what kind of component you were using, only that `Text` doesn't exist.  They may have renamed it.

Comment: Hi @Draco18s thank you very much for your response. The **text** component can be found [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html); it is a part of the Unity5's UI gui system. In this case the text component is part of a button gameobject instantiated to the scene

Comment: Ah, that's why I couldn't find it.  You may have to use `GetComponent(UI.Text);`

Comment: I tried this but to no avail. I would be surprised if referencing the UI class in the GetComponent function would fix it as GetComponent simply requires a component type (in my case Text) as its argument.

I have no idea why this process would have been altered in the latest Editor update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to slack referencing on my part; instead of referencing as `var buttonText = instButton.GetComponentInChildren(Text);` I should have been using `var buttonText : Text = instButton.GetComponentInChildren.<Text>();`.

Why this came to be an issue in 5.3.3 I'm not sure, but nonetheless the problem seems to be resolved.

Comment: Ah, yes,  that would have been a problem that we couldn't solve. Glad you figured it out.